# On Selenium Webdriver Unable to click Button

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<a href="#personModal" class="btn right" data-toggle="modal" style="margin-left:5px;"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Add Contact</a>
```

I wrote the following code:

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='view-list']/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='view-list']/div[1]/a[1]")).submit();
```

Both lines are not working

I have also tried using the Classname:

```
d.findElement(By.classname("btn right")).click();
```

This is also not working

Comment: show us your html. check the button is visible or no

Comment: Actually In application "Add contact" button was there ...if I use to click that button using Xpath and class name...both are not working,,,,In selenium web driver getting this error "Unable to find the element location"

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath: //a[.= " Add Contact"]
Make sure between "" you have exactly text of your link including spaces. What kind of error you get? And show us full html.

Answer (score 0):

Makesure the element you're trying to click is visible (bcoz, the `element present` may return true, but the `visibility` may return false)

If the element you're looking for is visible, then you can try the below code,

You can use the relative **XPath** to find the element based on the value,

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Add Contact')]
```

Or With **CSS selector**,

//("td[class='btn right'][value='Add Contact']");

Answer (score -1):

Please try this - Should work:

```
    d.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Add Contact")).click();
```

Comment: there is no problem in using the identifiers such as css/xpath/linktext, as you might see in the other answers, but the elements visibility matters the most in this context

Comment: Did the OP tell about element visibility? That's purely your opinion. I'm surprised.

Comment: If the partialLinkText can able to locate the button, then the relative path of css selector/ xpath should does that. So it is no point trying with partialLinkText, and it is same as the other answers

Comment: Sometimes partialLinkText works in places where css/xpath doesn't. I tried mine on OP's code and it did work. So, still surprised on your 'opinion'.

Comment: You believe? or you tried on OP's code? And did it work?

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes. do you have a rationale. i must say css/xpath too does work with the OP's code you tried. thats my point

Comment: Did you try your solution on OP's code? Did it work? Anyways, I'm not opinionated. So I will just leave it to the OP.